# opengraph objects only show default locale in stream

Tags: locale, facebook-opengraph

I have an opengraph object https://example.com/object that supports multiple locales, specifically `en_US` and `fr_FR` with the first as default.

Parsing it in Facebook's Object Debugger correctly shows both locales as `og:locale:alternate` properties and the default locale as `og:locale`. Clicking each locale link indeed shows the object in the expected locale.

However, when a user likes the object (passing https://example.com/object as object url, using any like-box locale, and no matter which locale is defined for the user in Facebook), her stream always shows the object in its default `en_US` locale.

Is this a Facebook issue, or did I miss anything?

**NOTE:** 
This question is similar to [this one](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7614603/facebook-meta-tags-scraped-with-locale-not-working). However, the focus there is on scraping the URL by Facebook, which works fine for me: both `fb_locale` and `X-Facebook-Locale` are correctly passed when the url is scraped. Here, the focus is on displaying the scraped url in the stream using the correct locale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is a bit confusing.

`og:locale` shouldn't be set to your default locale; it should be set to whichever locale you're currently returning.

Specifically, if Facebook requests `fb_locale=fr_FR`, you need to return `<meta property="og:locale" content="fr_FR">` in the response.

It does make sense. When Facebook sees `og:locale="en_US"` in the response, it thinks you didn't have a French page to return, so it uses the English content it's already got. It's just not documented very well at all.

Here are my Open Graph locale tags for English:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_CA" />
```

And for French:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="fr_CA" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_CA" />
```

On getting Facebook to actually use the right content in a dialog, your mileage may vary, but this will at least get the scraper to recognize your content.